# Add validation to dynamically created checkboxes jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, checkbox

I am working on dynamic form which is radio, checkbox are added dynamically. Unfortunately, I stuck in adding validation.

How to add **require** attribute to checkboxes ?

Following code

```
<ol type="a">
  <li><input type="radio" name="answer0[]">A</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="answer0[]">A</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="answer0[]">A</li>
</ol>
<ol type="a">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="answer1[]">A</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="answer1[]">A</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="answer1[]">A</li>
</ol>
```

1. Input type depends on question which is radio or checkbox
2. There could be any number of questions **answer1[], answer2[], answer3[]**

First approach as follows

```
$('ol').each(function (i) {
    $(this).find("input:first").prop("required", true);
});
```

Since input elements have same name radio type works fine. But checkbox required to be checked only first input.

Second

```
$('ol').each(function (i) {
    $("[name='answer"+i+"[]']").rules("add", {required:true});
});
```

But it gives following error

> Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined

How to add validation to checkbox at least one must be checked...

Comment: What plugin you are using for validation ?

Comment: jQuery validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay try this solution:

```
var rules = {};

$('ol [type="checkbox"], ol [type="radio"]').each(function(i,el){
    var name = $(el).attr('name');
    if(rules[name] === undefined){
        rules[name] = {
            required: true
        };
    }
});

$("#myform").validate({
    rules: rules
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works, nice approach getting **element name**.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
$('ol').each(function (i) {
    $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("required", true);
});
```

try checking length of checked checkboxes

```
$('ol').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length
```

Comment: Your approach make all checkboxes require to be checked.

Comment: ok then you can check length of checked checkboxes in each ol. check edited answer

Comment: Suppose there are 50 questions, I don't think it is good idea to check each questions checkboxes length.

Comment: you can loop through all ol wrap it under div, and inside ol loop through input

Answer (score 0):

I'd add the dynamic logic into "rules" directly. 
I recently solved my own problem where one form has two default submit buttons. Added rules as functions took care of it.